# Javascript - Event trigger when text input change but not with physical key board

Tags: javascript

I have created a virtual numeric keypad by Javascript that appears when the user focuses on `input` (by `onfocus` event). When clicking on this keypad buttons can type in that input. In this `input` another function runs by `onkeyup` event which means when the user types in this input by physical keyboard this function triggers.

```
<input type="text" id="nc" onkeyup="checkNationalCode(this);" onfocus="appearNumPad(this);"/>
```

The problem here:

When the user types by clicking on my virtual numeric keypad, `onkeyup` event doesn't trigger. I have tried some other event types instead `onkeyup` (for example `onchange`, `oninput` ,...) but non of them work.

Is there any event type that triggers and runs `checkNationalCode()` function when the user clicks on the keypads button (typing on the keypads button in `input`) or another why two run this function by user typing with my virtual keypad?

I can not use `onclick` event on the keypad buttons because `checkNationalCode()` is in one of my `input` but my virtual keypad is used for all of `input`.

The function that creates and appears on my keypad by ajax :

```
function appearNumPad(obj){
    document.getElementById("numPadContainer").style.display = "block";
    //step1:
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest;
    //step2:
    request.open("GET", "../common/numPad.php?inputID="+obj.id);
    //step3:
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("numPadContainer").innerHTML=this.responseText;
        }
     };
    //step4:
    request.send();
}
```

Comment: have you tried on blur?

Comment: tanx but i need function run during user typing . but onblur trigger when typing finish and the inputs onfocuas

Comment: Try adding something like `click` event on the buttons

Comment: tnx but i have explain it. the virtual key pad use for type many text input but this function is in one of text inputs. so on click vent on key pad buttons can't solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your virtual keypad key click handler, you could dispatch your desired event to the input like this.

```
const input = document.querySelector('#nc');
input.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup', {'key': '<key name>'}));
```

Comment: so tanx my dear friend. your solvtion is true and solved my problem